# Как реализовать поиск по ключу объекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть функция которая ищет `value` в объекте. Как можно сделать так, чтоб искать можно было по ключу?

Например сейчас работает так :

когда у функции `search('r', items)` аргумент `r`m то выдаст слова где есть `r`.

`// ["bar", "lorem", "dolor"]`

А было б неплохо если можно было искать и по ключам. Например так :

если аргументом будет `foo`, должно выдать: `// ["bar", "lorem", "dolor"]`

а если аргумент `bar` то должно выдать: `["amet","ipsum","dolor"]`

вся функция :

```js
function search(s, arr) {
  var matches = [];

  for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && arr[i][key].indexOf(s) > -1)
        matches.push(arr[i][key]);
    }
  }
  return matches;
};

var items = [{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "sit"
}, {
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}, {
  "foo": "dolor",
  "bar": "amet"
}];

search('r', items); // ["bar", "lorem", "dolor"]
```

Comment: А в чем сложность то. У вас в цикле уже есть `key` его и проверяте на равенство аргументу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналогично же:

```
function search(s, arr) {
  var matches = [];

  for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && key.indexOf(s) > -1) {
        matches.push(arr[i][key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return matches;
};

var items = [{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "sit"
}, {
  "foo": "lorem",
  "bar": "ipsum"
}, {
  "foo": "dolor",
  "bar": "amet"
}];

search('foo', items);
```